# Where is the best place for a man to pursue a divorce?

Tags: international, marriage, divorce, settlement

As far as divorce law goes, in what country and/or state is the best place for a man to get a divorce?  (I.e., where will he receive the most favorable terms?)

Comment: You need to be more explicit with what you mean. Unless you mean some states physically sever the man into two equal pieces, in which case I have follow up questions. Do you mean dividing the assets equally?

Comment: Everywhere that has equal rights for men and women. You both became one, so when you split it should , in most cases, be in half.

Comment: Some countries do not recognize divorce (e.g., Philippines). Some countries are heavily biased in favor of wife, especially with respect to custody of children (e.g., Japan).

Answer (score 3):

Your options are generally limited by where you have (or can establish) residency, along with where your communal property is held.

There are (decreasing numbers of) jurisdictions known as "[divorce mills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divorce_mill)" that have notoriously lenient rules for establishing residency and completing divorces.